# ListBox with GroupStyle scrolls by group, not by item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a `ListBox` with a `GroupStyle`. If i use the `GroupStyle` the `ScrollViewer` of the `ListBox` scrolls by group rather that item. So if the group has more items than fit on the screen the user never sees the ones off screen. If i comment out the `GroupStyle` the `ScrollViewer` works like intened an scrolls item by item. (I added the `ControlTemplate` to try different things).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BusStopsFlattend" Source="{Binding BusStopsFlat}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CountryCode" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BusStopsFlattend}}" Margin="48,0,48,60">
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0,24,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <controls:IconViewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IconData="{StaticResource IconPathPencilOutline}" IconSize="72" Margin="0,0,24,0" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="32" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" /> 
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,48,0,24" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` property to `False` to use physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling. Keep in mind that this will disable virtualization if you decide to use it.

Comment: But I want to use logical scrolling. Just not by group but by each item of a group.

Comment: In the end I didn't find a way to make it work. So I set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = false` and manually calculated the avg height of the `ListBoxItem`.